# how to automatically enter generated numbers into a program as input

Tags: python, combinations

I have this script which takes the numbers you give it and gives you all the possible combinations.

```
import itertools
import sys
perms = itertools.permutations([1,2,3])

for perm in list(perms):
    print perm
```

Want i want it to do is after it is finished generating them to put them in as input into another program or script. for example i generate all the possible combinations for 1 2 3 it then plugs those numbers into a password protected .py?

Comment: Side note: You don't need to (and shouldn't) do `for perm in list(perms):`. Just do `for perm in perms:` instead. The whole point of iterators is that you can iterate over them directly. You only need to make a list out of one if you need to iterate over it repeatedly (or in random-access order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output to a different program
example:

```
> program2 | program1
```

Will run program1 and send the output to program2 which is then run.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is from outside of Python—either use a shell pipeline, as Jean-Bernard Pellerin shows, or just store the data in a file with a known location.

But if you want to do this all within Python, making one program drive the other, you can do that too.

The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module lets you run other programs, and control their input and output and so on. For example:

```
import itertools
import subprocess
import sys

perms = itertools.permutations([1,2,3])

child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'password_protected.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for perm in list(perms):
    child.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(perm))

retcode = child.wait()
sys.exit(retcode)
```

From the names, I'm guessing what you *actually* want to do is run the other program over and over, once for each permutation, and do something with either the return code or the output. To do that, you just move the `subprocess` stuff inside the loop. But you can also make it a lot simpler if you're not trying to stream stuff to the child.

For example, if `password_protected.py` exits with retcode 2 when you give it a bad password, you can do this:

```
import itertools
import subprocess
import sys

perms = itertools.permutations([1,2,3])

for perm in list(perms):
    child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'password_protected.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    child.communicate('{}\n'.format(perm))
    if child.returncode != 2:
        print '{} is the password!'.format(perm)
        break
```